# sending data from controller to model

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have the following code on my site which sending data to Ajax and works normal. It is about add to cart.

```
       public function adding()
        {
            $id_lap=$this->input->post('id_lap');  
            $num_items=$this->input->post('num_items'); 
            $price=$this->input->post('price');

             if($id_lap !='') 
             {

                     $this->session->set_userdata('num_items',$num_items);
                     $this->session->set_userdata('price_new',$price);


                     $response=array(
                        'status'=>1,
                        'num_items'=>$num_items,
                        'price_new'=>$price
                     );

             } else {

                 $response=array(
                    'status'=>0
                 );
             }

             echo json_encode($response);                      
        }
```

When I want to send data to model also where I want to write data into database along with IP adress which I will collect with model. When I add new row anywhere my Ajax crashed. Part of code which I want to add is:

```
    $this->users_mod->AddSesija($id_lap,$price);
```

And Ajax code which I am using is :

```
function Addtocart(id,prices)
{
    var id_lap=id;
    var ajaxURL= BASE_URL +'home/adding';
    var num_items = parseInt($('#num_items').html()) + 1;
    var price = parseInt($('#price_b').html());
    var price_new = price + prices;
    /*console.log(id_lap +' '+num_items+' '+price_new);  

    $('#num_items').html(num_items);
    $('#price_b').html(price_new); */
   $.ajax({
        url:ajaxURL,
        type:'POST',
        data:{'id_lap':id_lap,'num_items':num_items,'price':price_new},
        success:function(response)
        {
             var parsed = JSON.parse(response);

             if(parsed.status ==1)
             {
                 $('#num_items').html(parsed.num_items); 
                 $('#price_b').html(parsed.price_new); 
             }
        }
    } 
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you get any specific error in the crash?

Comment: Just doesn't work, but if I open console there is error: POST http://localhost/prvisajt/home/adding 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Post your model code too!!!

Comment: Ok, so your server is throwing the error. Do you see any error on your server side? You should have log lines in you adding method to help identify the progress

Comment: ` public function AddSesija($id_lap,$price)
    {
        $id_adress=$this->input->ip_address();
        
        $data=array(
            'ip_adress'=>$ip_adress,
            'id_lap'=>$id_lap,
            'cena'=>$price
        );
        
        $this->db->insert('sesije',$data);
    }`

Comment: Model isn't important, if I add a new row in controller he stops working so problem is in controller by me

Comment: Please post your code in your question not in your comment!!!

Comment: I don't know how, I have tried

Comment: click of edit button below your question and edit your question

Comment: And then what, how to edit to be in code mode, how!!!!!!!!! Model isn't important !!!!!!!!

Comment: what row you added in your controller which cause error???

Comment: $this->users_mod->AddSesija($id_lap,$price);

Comment: Does it show any result when you get response from server?

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Vladimir Glisovic in concept. we know that for adding or inserting group of data we should bind them into an array.

Sample:

```
$data=array( 'ip_adress'=>$ip_adress, 'id_lap'=>$id_lap, 'cena'=>$price );
```

N.b: get IP address from PHP code keep in $ip_address.

Then pass the data to model with the CI syntax.

Model calling in Controller:

```
 $this->users_mod->AddSesija($data);
```

Now write the inserting code in the model file as

```
public function AddSesija($data){

insertion code here..... 
}
```

### Hope it will help you.

Thanks!

Amadercode